# Canvas Video slowing down animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Whenever I play the video to the canvas it is slowing the animation that I have simultaneously running. Once the video has stopped playing the animation returns to normal speed. Any idea what can be causing this?

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border: 5px solid red;" ></canvas>  
<p id="text"> Increase/Decrease Speed</p>
<script>
var x = 0;
var y = 500;
var speed = 10;
var isRight = true;
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = 'gold.mp4';
video.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(video);
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

video.onplay = function() {
    draw();
};

document.getElementById('text').innerText = speed;
document.getElementById('btnAdd').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (isRight) speed++;
    else speed--;
    document.getElementById('text').innerText = speed;
});

document.getElementById('btnSub').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (isRight) speed--;
    else speed++;
    document.getElementById('text').innerText = speed;  
});

function animate() {
    reqAnimFrame = window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame;
    reqAnimFrame(animate);
    x += speed;
    if (x <= 0 || x >= 775) {
        speed = -speed;
        isRight = !isRight;
    }
    document.getElementById('text').innerText = speed;
    draw();
}

function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.clearRect(0, 400, 800, 775);
    context.fillStyle = "#ff00ff";
    context.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40);

if(video.paused || video.ended) return false;
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
    setTimeout(draw, 20);       
}

animate();
</script>
```

Comment: What browsers can you replicate this problem with?

Comment: Its having that problem in Firefox seems to run fine in IE

Comment: Firefox is notoriously sluggish with various aspects of both canvas and animations. I'm not saying that's the problem, but given its past, I wouldn't be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting `draw()` twice. Every time rAF runs draw() is called then draw() calls itself which means you are drawing double:

```
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.clearRect(0, 400, 800, 775);
    context.fillStyle = "#ff00ff";
    context.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40);

    if(video.paused || video.ended) return false;
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

    setTimeout(draw, 20);    /// <--- HERE is the problem
}
```

This line shouldn't be necessary for this to work. Hope this helps.